# Checking if variable exists for child class

Tags: php, oop, variables, exists

I'm creating global setters and getters for my parent class since I don't want to create them for each child class variable (but I will occasionally overwrite the parent global setter / getter).

I'm using __call with it and I'm parsing the method name like this:

```
if (strtolower(substr($method, 0, 3)) == "set") {
  $variable = strtolower(substr($method, 3));
}
```

The question is how can I check if the $variable is set for the child class (the one that is extending the main one);

If I do:

```
if ($this->$variable)
```

I suppose it first check if it exists on the child class and then it checks if it exists on the main class. I want it only to check the child class, is this possible to do?

I know there's parent:: but is there an equivalent for child?

**EDIT:
People are not understanding what I'm asking.
I know how to check if the property exists. What I want to know is how to check if the property exists for the CHILD class, not for the MAIN class.
(class CHILD extends MAIN)**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't understand why you use the `__call` approach. If your code is properly object oriented you don't need to resort to such a exotic solution.

Comment: I have hundreds of properties and I don't want to fill my classes with: setThis, setThat, setThose, setThem (and same for get). I only want to create those functions when they do something else than set or get the data (for example sanitizing).

Comment: That problem could be solved with one abstract class those other classes inherit from. The other benefit it that the contract becomes clear. With `__call` it all becomes magic.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show me an example. Sounds interesting!

Comment: If you can provide some sample classes that describe your situation and how you plan to use them an example can be created.

Comment: I have Main class that has __call function and in short/pseudo it has if (substr($method, 0, 3) == "set") { $this->substr($method, 3) = $property; } and same for get. The Child class has a bunch of protected properties which are setted and getted through the Main class. If i want to add some special handling to a setter & getter I create it to the Child class and then it will override the magic setter and or getter for that property.

Answer (score 2):

In common case there's [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) function, but is will not fit this case. Use [property_exists()](https://www.php.net/property_exists) instead:

```
class Foo
{
    public $pub = null;
}

$obj = new Foo();

var_dump(isset($obj->pub), property_exists('Foo', 'pub')); //false, true
```

-that's because if proprty exists, but is null, `isset()` will return false - and you'll not be able to differ the case, when it does not exist.

If it's about dynamic properties - then you should pass object and not class name to `property_exists()` since property may absent in class and then dynamically added to object.

Now, if we're saying about *which class* is declaring property, you can use [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getdeclaringclass.php) in PHP, like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public $pub = null;
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
}

$obj = new Bar();

$ref = new ReflectionObject($obj);

var_dump($ref->getProperty('pub')->getDeclaringClass()->getName() == 'Bar');//false
var_dump($ref->getProperty('pub')->getDeclaringClass()->getName() == 'Foo');//true
```

Comment: Same answer to you as for Shankar, the problem is not that I don't know how to check it. I want to check if the CHILD class has that property. I don't want it to return true if the MAIN class has it.

Comment: Seems to be an awful hard way to do something so simple. :(

Comment: Well, If I understood correctly, you want to get class, which is declaring your property. When you're doing extension of class, all it's public & protected (but not private) properties will be inherited to child class unless child class overrides them. So in child class you will also _have them by definition_. So it will be no difference which class declared them - and that's because you need to involve reflection functionality to discover this thing

Comment: Hmm.. I'll give you an example. On my main class I have the global setter and some global methods like Save() etc. On the child I have properties like $id, $name, $address etc. And I want to set these values with the global setter. All works fine but I have some variables on the main class like $db etc. that I don't want to be able to set ever. That's why I want to check if the property exists on the child because then it's "settable".

Comment: If that's the case, why not make `$db` a `private` variable? Then children can't overwrite it

Comment: I feel so stupid right now. I somehow thought that if the global setter is in the main class it can access the private properties too. Thanks Machavity!

Comment: @unska that's not stupidity - it's ok if you don't know something. But to the future - you should explain any significant circumstances in your question - then you'll get proper answer quick and precise

Comment: You are right! Thanks for spending your time on me. Have an awesome weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of **`isset`** ??

```
if (isset($this->$variable))
```

Comment: As I told earlier, this will check if it exists on the child or the main class and I want it to check the child only.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
if(property_exists($get_class($this),$variable)){}
```